# Adjust angle of picture to fit shape in Powerpoint

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

[image]

How to adjust the degree/angle of a picture/image so that it fits a shape in PPT

[image]

[image]

I am trying to get my image into the black area of the PPT shape, but when I set it to the shape it stays in a horizontal projection

The angle/Degree of the PPT shape is roughly 51.5 degrees

I tried rotating the shape in Gimp

But Gimp kept clipping the image to the background

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to assume that PPT stands for power point? If so, could you update your question title to say power point instead? This will help with making the question searchable. In gimp, you need to expand the image canvas before you apply any rotation effects. Alternately, you could try rotating the image in PowerPoint. I'm unable to provide detailed instructions for this at the time but I can guarantee there's numerous tutorials on YouTube for both pieces of software.

Comment: In GIMP, after rotation/distortion, click *Image > Fit Canvas to layers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a screenshot of the full size PowerPoint slide

In GIMP click *File > Create > from clipboard*

Copy and paste the pattern, click Layer > New Layer

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Distort the pattern to fit the shape, hit Enter to confirm the transform.

For example:

[image]

Finally hide the bottom screenshot layer, crop if necessary, then export the image file as a PNG